# how to combine Y or N or null values

Tags: sql, oracle

**still not found the solution described in update 2**

thx for help

ill try to explain my issue with my poor english. hope someone can solve my problem.

i got the following table

```
A      B
1      Y
2      null
3      Y
```

what result i want?
in dependency of the rank in column A i want to combine column B.

the result in that example is ... no result
the reason is because there is a null in rank 2 and the next and the last rank (=3) has a value (=Y).

next example

```
A      B
1      Y
2      null
3      null
```

result i want is

```
A   B
1   Y
```

because the way after is free... means 2 and the last 3 has null

another example

```
A    B
1    null
2    N
3    null
```

again no result is what i want in this case. because first =1 has null value.

i try now to conclude ... if n(e.g. 2) of column B has value Y or N then the elements bevor (in this 1) must have the value Y or N.

thank you very much. i tried different technics without any success...

**UPDATE 1**
thank you fast comment

some example dates with expected result

```
example 1
A   B
1   Y
2   N
3   null
4   null

expected result
A    B
2    N

example 2
A   B
1   N
2   Y
3   N
4   null

expected result
A   B
3   N

example 3
A   B
1   null
2   Y
3   Y
4   null

expected result
no result

example 4
A   B
1   Y
2   Y
3   null
4   Y

expected result
no result
```

**UPDATE 2**

forget the basic case

```
A   B
1   Y
2   N
3   Y
```

expected result

```
A   B
3   N
```

Comment: If you could provide sample date in a table format that would help out a lot.  It's kind of hard to follow what you want.

Comment: if y show the value if n or null dont, this is it?

Comment: I thought I understood what you wanted until I read your conclusion.

Comment: Will there always be a group of 3 rows?  Is this what you are looking for:

If B value in row 1 is 'Y', and B values in rows 2 and 3 are NULL, then return row 1, else don't return anything?

Comment: sorry for my bad conclusion :) no it can be more then 3. yes or 1 and 2 has Y or N and the rest has null. or 1, 2, 3... has Y or N and 4, 5,6 ... has null

Comment: Your new example will help out a lot.  Should we assume that the entire data set will be evaluated once, then replaced with new data and evaluated again?  Otherwise, how do you know if you've reached the end of your table and can use the logic against it?  For instance, how do we know that there isn't a value in row 5 in example 1?

Comment: yes lets assume the entire data is evaluated once. like in the example until 3 or 4 :)

Comment: After posting that comment I looked at your example and realized I was a little off base.

Comment: Your very first example taken with the very last produce nothing but confusion in my mind. I understood nothing.

Comment: +1 for illustrating your request. Consider editing your first example so the desired results has the same format as the other examples. Right now you verbal description is difficult to understand. Good luck!

Comment: Reading this make me feel like I'm playing Mastermind.

Answer (score 3):

Establish the highest value of A where B is Y or N, and the lowest value of A where B is null.  Provided the first value is lower than the second value you have a valid result set.

```
select yt.A 
       , yt.B
from 
    ( select max(case when B is not null then A else null end) as max_b_yn
             , min(case when B is null then A else null end) as min_b_null
      from your_table ) t1 
   , your_table yt
where ( t1.min_b_null is null 
        or t1.max_b_yn < t1.min_b_null )
and yt.A = t1.max_b_yn 
/
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but i have the case when every row has a valid number (see update 2). the query wont work for that case. it checks against null

Comment: APC thx you... but its still not the result i want. see Update 2. If any preceeding value is N then the hole value is N. This works only for the max value. i need to group them...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the last row before the first NULL.  If this is correct, then the following gets what you want:

```
 select t.*
 from t join
      (select min(A) as NullA from t where B is NULL) t2
      on t.A = t2.NullA - 1
```

Ah, I see.  To get the last row with an "N":

```
 select t.*
 from t
 where t.A in (select max(A) as MaxA
               from t join
                    (select min(A) as NullA from t where B is NULL) t2
                    on t.A < t2.NullA
                where t.B = 'N'
               )
```

Comment: It looks like he is only wanting the last row with 'N'

Comment: Why does example 4 have no result?  Shouldn't it be "2, Y"?

Comment: Hmm, ok.  So grab the last row with a value in column B as long as a NULL does not precede it?

Comment: @GordonLinoff because after null there is the value Y :)

Comment: @N1tr0 exactly. Thats one of the conditions :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I have what you need.   It grabs the last row that has a value in column B as long as there isn't a row with a NULL that precedes it.

```
select MAX(A), B
from table_a
where B IS NOT NULL
and table_a.A > (
          select MIN(A)
          FROM table_a
          WHERE B IS NULL
         )
Group by B
```

Comment: Hmm, you're right but I don't understand why.  I walked through that example and it should have returned row #2.  Can you shed some light on this?

Comment: I thought I had a clean and uncomplicated solution too.  Oh well.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: yes thank you. while searching for the solution i thought a bunch of time that i found the solution.

Answer (score -3):

```
select top 1 A, B
from #Temp
where B is not null
order by A desc
```

or

```
select top 1 A, B
from #Temp
where B = 'N'
order by A desc
```

Comment: Alas this is not valid syntax in Oracle SQL.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I thought it was a T-SQL question.